# How to use task and state in jbpm 4.4

Tags: state, task, jbpm, business-process-management

I am trying to use jbpm 4.4 for a workflow solution where, the UI is provided by a web application.
Here I am trying to assign a certain task to a user and expect him/her to perform certain action on it...

like "Approve", "Reject" and "Approve with remarks"..

All of these actions need to have separate processing.

What I am not able to understand is,
should I use a task element :

OR a state (wait state) element:

Idea is, I will let the user click on the  "Approve", "Reject" and "Approve with remarks" buttons in an jsp page and I want to convey this to the process engine, through jbpm APIs.

Need some help/pointers on this.

TIA

Comment: You should use a task. In the you should add the transitions "Approve", "Reject" and "Approve with remarks"

Comment: @Rodrigo thanks for the answer. Got some answers in the jbpm community forum at jboss site. Yes that's the way to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rodrigo has mentioned, need to use Task element. This answers the question.